# Node.js + Express 4 + Passport.js how to get the list of all currently logged in users?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have setup my Node.js server as following:

```
var Express = require('express');
var Path = require('path');
var Favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var Logger = require('morgan');
var CookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var BodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var Mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Routes = require('./routes/index');
var Users = require('./routes/users');
//var Login = require('./routes/login');

var App = Express();

// view engine setup
App.set('views', Path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
App.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
App.use(Logger('dev'));
App.use(BodyParser.json());
App.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
App.use(CookieParser());
App.use(require('express-session')({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
App.use(Passport.initialize());
App.use(Passport.session());
App.use(require('stylus').middleware(Path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
App.use(Express.static(Path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

App.use('/', Routes);
//App.use('/users', Users);
//App.use('/login', Login);

// passport config
var Account = require('./models/account');
Passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Account.authenticate()));
Passport.serializeUser(Account.serializeUser());
Passport.deserializeUser(Account.deserializeUser());

// mongoose
Mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/passport_local_mongoose_express4');

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
App.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (App.get('env') === 'development') {
    App.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
App.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

module.exports = App;
```

Authenitcation works very well and now I wish to get a list of all logged in users on my dashboard. How can I get it?

Comment: You have to monitor requests and create set with users those were requesting in some recent time interval like 5 minutes. At least I'd try doing it that way.